# What is the ClojureScript analogue of typeof ... undefined from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, undefined, clojurescript

I'm seeing lots of code using the pattern:

```
if (typeof a.b === 'undefined') { ...
```

Now I'm translating this to:

```
(if (nil? (-.b a)) ...
```

Is that appropriate - or am I losing some crucial data?

My question is: **What is the ClojureScript analogue of `typeof ... undefined` from JavaScript?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For checking for possibly `undefined` references you can use [`cljs.core/exists?`](https://github.com/cljsinfo/cljs-api-docs/blob/catalog/refs/cljs.core/existsQMARK.md):

```
(when-not (exists? js/unknownReference)
  ...)
```